# Compiling PHP Imagick Extension for XAMPP 1.7.3 on OS X Lion

Tags: php, apache, xampp, osx-lion, imagick

I'm having some trouble getting the PHP Imagick extension compiled and running with XAMPP 1.7.3 on OS X Lion.

I get the following error in my PHP error log when launching Apache (and the extension doesn't show in the `phpinfo()` output):

```
[16-Aug-2011 12:42:31] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
```

I installed the XAMPP development package.

I used Homebrew to install Imagick 6.7.1-1:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew link imagemagick
```

To install the Imagick extension I used PECL provided with XAMPP:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
sudo ./pecl install imagick
```

When prompted for the location of ImageMagick I've tried the following paths (with the same result):

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/Cellar
```

You can see the entire output here: https://gist.github.com/1149849

Additionally I tried grabbing the Imagick PECL (3.0.1 and 3.1.0b) tar from the PECL website and compiling from scratch:

```
/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin.phpize
./configure --with-imagick=/usr/local/bin --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.3.1 
make
sudo make install
make test
```

You can see the output here: https://gist.github.com/1149875

I've stumbled across a few articles about this topic on various website, none of which have helped me resolve it.

I've also tried MacPorts for ImageMagic, with the same result (using `/opt/local` as the path during compile).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Note: For the record, I'm able to reproduce this issue on another OS X Lion machine.

Comment: I can get it installed and it is there from command line phpinfo, but not web phpinfo???? Verified it is the same php installation

Answer (score 0):

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '../imagick.so' {Snip}....no suitable image found.  Did find:
    imagick.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0`

It clearly says, the extension is there but architecture is not same your kernel. perhaps you are booted into 64bit kernel & trying to run 32version or vice versa.

Just boot into kernel with correct arch

[1] [Mac OS X v10.6: Starting up with the 32-bit or 64-bit kernel](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3773)

Comment: Hi Gaurish, thanks for pointing that out, however booting into i386 or x86_64 kernel mode and recompiling ImageMagick gives me the exact same result in my error logs.